# FK constraint with ViewModel MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a little problem using MVC4 and Entity Framework. I have an entity "Person" which is composed of an other entity named "ProductPackageCategories". I have also a ViewModel "PersonViewModel". In the "Create Person" view, I can create my new person and specify the category with a dropdownlist component. Usually, when I click on the submit button, the data are stored in the database. In my case, I retrieve all the data but not the ProductPackageCategory Id. Does anybody have an idea about this problem?

The Exception Message :

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\MAARAB\DESKTOP\PROJECT\2013-03-01_4-9_MA-OS_BUSI MATERIAL PROJECT\BUSIMATERIAL\BUSIMATERIAL\APP_DATA\BUSIMATERIAL.MDF", table "dbo.bm_ProductPackageCategories", column 'Id_ProductPackageCategory'.
```

The statement has been terminated.

My Create Actions in PersonController :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Person/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PersonViewModel personViewModel)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Persons.AddObject(personViewModel.person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }



            ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name", personViewModel.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory);

            return View(personViewModel);
        }
```

My ViewModel :

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person person { get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        person = new Person();
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

My Create View :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.PersonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.NumNat)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.NumNat)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.NumNat)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.StartDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.StartDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.StartDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.EndDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.EndDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.EndDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.Upgrade)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.Upgrade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.Upgrade)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Choose one...")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.HouseToWorkKilometers)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.HouseToWorkKilometers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.HouseToWorkKilometers)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Choose one...")
```

with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory,
    (SelectList)ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory,
    "Choose one..."
)
```

so that the `person.Id_ProductPackageCategory` property on your model is correctly bound from the selected value in the dropdown when the form is submitted to your HttpPost action.

Comment: Thanks again for your help ! Just a little problem, for the "model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory" part, VS displays an error which is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"...

Comment: My Mistake, I forgot to modify "DropDownList" in "DropdownListFor", thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use strongly-typed-html-helpers to bind property to model. Use `DropDownListFor` instead of `DropDownList`

controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory, ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Just a little problem, for the "model => model.person.Id_ProductPackageCategory" part, VS displays an error which is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"...

Comment: Make sure you add `using System.Data`,`using System.Data.Entity` and `Using System.Linq;`

Comment: My Mistake, I forgot to modify "DropDownList" in "DropdownListFor", thanks !